# Shebang in windows

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, shebang

Since Windows doesn't support shebang  like Unix-like operating systems where you can specify the interpreter in the beginning of the script:

Is putting it in the scripts and running them on Windows going to cause a problem?

I tried it for PHP and it seems to be fine. Is it possible that other interpreters see it as a syntactic error or it's gonna be fine no matter what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most language runtimes that run across platforms know about the shebang and ignore it, regardless of platform, or (as in the case of Perl), known about it and do the right thing with it (by invoking the desired program).  So if you're using a language like PHP which runs across a variety of OSes, then you should have no problems.

In addition, many of these languages ignore the shebang because in that language the hash mark (`#`) starts a comment, so even if they lack special handling for it, they'll ignore it nevertheless.

The only time you might ever see a problem with a script is if you have a language where `#` is not a comment and it runs only on Windows, but I know of very few languages where that's the case.